# Scala function accepts different type

Tags: scala

I am trying to figure out why the following Scala code compile?

```
trait List[+A]
case object Nil extends List[Nothing]
case class Cons[+A](head: A, tail: List[A]) extends List[A]

def map[A, B](as: List[A])(f: A => B): List[B] = as match {
  case Nil         => Nil
  case Cons(x, xs) => Cons(f(x), map(xs)(f))
}

def tester[A, B](as: List[A])(f1: A => List[B]) = map(as)(f1)
```

As per my understanding, `tester` should not compile because the definition of `map` says it accepts two parameters: a list list a function of type `A => B`.

However, in `tester` function I have function `f1` which is of type `A => List[B]`, so, as the type of the arguments mismatch, I thought that the compiler should throw error. But the code is compiling fine.

Could you please help me to understand why the code is compiling here?

Comment: `.map` should declare a type parameter `A`, otherwise this one will shadow the type parameter `A` at the trait level (and is useless in this case anyway)

Comment: @cchantep `map` is outside the trait.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the `tester[A,B]` method you are in fact calling `map[A, List[B]]`.

Maybe the code is easier to understand if you write the tester method with a different type parameters, then in the invocation of `map`, `A = C` and `B = List[D]`.

```
def tester[C, D](as: List[C])(f1: C => List[D]): List[List[D]] = {
  map[C, List[D]](as)(f1)
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the response. I actually forgot that the Scala compiler infer the type of parameters from the argument passed.  How ever I still don't under stand   why in  tester  method the map is actually map[A,List[B]] ?  As the type of as is  List[A] and  type of f1 is A=>List[B] . So shouldn't the map be map[List[A], A=>List[B] ] ?

Comment: @Somenath the compiler infers the type parameters of map such that the arguments `as` and `f` in the invocation are compatible. Since `f1:A => List[B]`, `map` must be `map[A, List[B]]`

Answer (score 1):

I think your misunderstanding comes from the fact that you're assuming that the `A` and `B` types are common to both `map` and `tester`, while they are actually locally defined. For the purpose of this example, let's rename the `B` of `tester` into `C`. This means that the `B` of `map` will actually be `List[C]`.